# how can I change the js built-in objects properties?

Tags: javascript, dom

I do this:
`Element.toggle = Element.classList.toggle`
and I get an error.
how can I do this in the right way? thanks.

Comment: Seems weird you would want to do that

Comment: Can you provide some additional information about what you're trying to accomplish or why you don't want to use the default? "The right way" is really to use `Element.classList.toggle`

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Because I can guarantee you that there is no reason to do this.

Comment: `Element` doesn't even have a static `classList` property

Comment: @Phil It does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: @Ben it's not static though. It belongs to the `Element` prototype

Comment: @Phil fair point, which is why the answer to this question is long and esoteric and probably not going to come from me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the HTMLElement prototype

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.toggle = function (cls, flag) {
  this.classList.toggle(cls, flag)
}

var test = document.querySelector("#test")
test.toggle('yellow')
```

```css
div.yellow {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Maybe, there should be a note that it's exactly the kind of prototype extension that will kill browser's optimization because it will have to recalculate the shape of all the protos that inherits from Element (and there a few) https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/prototypes#validity-cells